# MVC 5 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap") error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, bootstrap-5

_Layout.cshtml file fails when attempting to render the bootstrap 5 script bundle (works for earlier versions of bootstrap)

[Bundle.Config File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAvuc.png)

[_Layout Debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWKgC.png)

[Scripts Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuliz.png)

Comment: try changing "new ScriptBundle" to "new Bundle".

Comment: I'm having a very similar problem... my menus are no longer redendering... I tried the change suggested above, as well as the change suggested in the answer below... no luck

Comment: @ManojSalvi You should make this as an answer. It worked for me.

Comment: @jewishspiderweb I have posted my suggestion as an answer as asked by you so it may help others as well who face the same issue. you may check and upvote if it worked for you.

Comment: Would be useful to include your config as part of the question (rather than screenshot) as if the image goes this question becomes less useful.

Answer (score 78):

Try changing "new ScriptBundle" to "new Bundle" in your "RegisterBundles" within BundleConfig:

```
bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));
```

Comment: This was the fix for me.

Comment: This also worked for me.

Comment: Also worked for me. Does someone knows why this answer works? The sudden change when "ScriptBundle" worked and then from build to build, it stops working to then have to change it to "Bundle" ... I found that weird! :/

Comment: This solution was posted almost a year ago...has anyone found out WHY changing the constructor call from ScriptBundle() to Bundle() works?

Comment: @EastofNowhere I think that this may provide an answer. See post by Bruce-SqlWork from jan 9th. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/502208/-42.html - "Bootstrap 4 & 5 use newer syntax. You need to update your bundling software to one that support current css and JavaScript syntax. It looks like you are using system.web.optimization, which hasn’t been updated since 2014, so it does not appear an update exists for it". In other words, using just `Bundle` instead of `ScriptBundle` leaves out some minifying and other optimisations.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue after updating bootstrap to the latest (v5.0.2) via Nuget. I see an answer above about changing ScriptBundle to Bundle with minified js. It is not a real solution for this issue. Script bundling is used to minify scripts only on release mode. We need unminified version on debug mode for debugging. So if you are already using minified js, you do not need to add it to bundleconfig.

I tried bundling with both bootstrap.js and bootstrap.bundle.js and got the same exception at script render phase.

I trimmed very long stacktrace as below:

```
System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=WebGrease
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseObjectLiteralProperty(Boolean isBindingPattern)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseObjectLiteral(Boolean isBindingPattern)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseLeftHandSideExpression(Boolean isMinus)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseUnaryExpression(Boolean& isLeftHandSideExpr, Boolean isMinus)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseExpressionList(JSToken terminator)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseMemberExpression(AstNode expression, List`1 newContexts)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseLeftHandSideExpression(Boolean isMinus)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseUnaryExpression(Boolean& isLeftHandSideExpr, Boolean isMinus)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseExpressionStatement(Boolean fSourceElement)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseStatement(Boolean fSourceElement, Boolean skipImportantComment)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseBlock()
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseArrowFunction(AstNode parameters)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseLeftHandSideExpression(Boolean isMinus)
   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseUnaryExpression(Boolean& isLeftHandSideExpr, Boolean isMinus)
```

I think there is a js format issue in new bootstrap.js or bootstrap.bundle.js which causes the parser crash.

Answer (score 3):

As @Manoj Salvi commented, Bootstrap 5 can be successfully bundled with:

```
bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/scripts/core").Include("~/content/scripts/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this as well.  After experimenting, I found that by moving the following two lines to the *head* section instead of the very last lines of the *body* section it seems to work.  However, is this the correct way to solve the problem?

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")

The reason being that when I left those two lines at the bottom of the razor page, it would run but dropdowns in the navbar no longer worked.  However, when I moved those two lines to the head it seems to work fine.

My BundleConfig class:

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on bundling, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at https://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
            "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
            "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
            "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
            "~/Content/site.css"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, was there something else you did to get the Nav bar to work correctly?

Answer (score -1):

public class BundleConfig
{
// Paketleme hakkında daha fazla bilgi için lütfen https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862 adresini ziyaret edin.
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
"~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Geliştirme yapmak ve öğrenme kaynağı olarak yararlanmak için Modernizr uygulamasının geliştirme sürümünü kullanın. Ardından
        // üretim için hazır. https://modernizr.com adresinde derleme aracını kullanarak yalnızca ihtiyacınız olan testleri seçin.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));

        bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                   "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                   "~/Scripts/respond.js",
                   "~/Content/site.css"));
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

create new mvc project  go to file manager copy all Script and bootstrap files paste your running project.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -6):

Try downgrading your bootstrap version.  I was on 5.1 and I downgraded to 4.6 and it works now.

Comment: I dont think the OP is looking to downgrade but to have a solution with the version mentioned